# Over the next 2 weeks

Tags: prepositions, time, future, dates

I need to clarify the time mentioned in this sentence:

> Can you please provide me a few dates and times that will suit you **over the next 2-3 weeks**?

So the dates mentioned should be any day from now or it will be someday after 14 days from now?

Thank you very much

Comment: Note that best practice is to offer a few fixed times rather than *Anytime is good*: "I have tomorrow at 2PM, or Mondays and Tuesdays at 11AM."

Answer (score 1):

This context doesn't intend "over" to mean "greater than," but "spread across." So yes, the expected range is between now and 3 weeks from now.

(Also, before someone mentions it, context and common sense prevent any potential confusion that might have arisen around what the "over" phrase modifies: Of course it's "dates and times," not "provide.")

Answer (score 0):

It has to be "during" the next 2-3 weeks.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/over_1?q=over)) **during**
> ♦ We'll discuss it over lunch.
> ♦ Over the next few days they got to know the town well.
> ♦ She has not changed much over the years.
> ♦ He built up the business over a period of ten years.